# EF core self referencing many-to-many with combined primary key

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have a project task class and each task may have multiple preceding tasks and multiple tasks may be dependent on it

```
public class Task
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
    public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }
    public List<TaskTask> TaskPrecedings { get; set; }
    public List<TaskTask> TaskPreskDependents { get; set; }
}

public class TaskTask
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Task TaskPreceding { get; set; }
    public Guid TaskPrecedingId { get; set; }
    public Task TaskPreskDependent { get; set; }
    public Guid TaskPreskDependentId { get; set; }
}
```

Configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Task>()
            .HasKey(k => new { k.Id, k.ProjectId});

modelBuilder.Entity<TaskTask>()
            .HasOne(a => a.TaskPreceding)
            .WithMany(b => b.TaskPreskDependent)
            .HasForeignKey(f => f.TaskPrecedingId);

modelBuilder.Entity<TaskTask>()
            .HasOne(a => a.TaskPreskDependent)
            .WithMany(b => b.TaskPreceding)
            .HasForeignKey(f => f.TaskPreskDependentId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

While I try to migrate, I get the following error:

> The relationship from 'TaskTask.TaskPreceding' to 'Task.TaskPreskDependent' with foreign key properties {'TaskPrecedingId' : Guid} cannot target the primary key {'Id' : Guid, 'ProjectId' : Guid} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of compatible foreign key properties for this relationship.

Is there anyone who can help me? Thank you!

Comment: why are you using a composite primary key for Task? That is causing the issue, if you want to have a composite primary key, than your foreign keys pointing to this primary key have to be composite as well. Although I think you shouldn't use a composite key for Task in the first place.

Comment: It is due to some design issue, Project is an aggregate root

Comment: I don't think that means it has to be a composite key. But anyway, then you should define your foreign key similarly and the error should go away.